Most efficient way to wire kitchen lighting?
Working on my kitchen renovation, and I've drawn up the following diagram for three-way switching of kitchen lights.  Looking for feedback into whether this is the best / easiest way, or if there is another way.  I believe if I wanted to wire with the load between the switches, the amount of wire is essentially the same since I need an extra traveller wire going from the first light to the last?
The panel is located almost directly underneath the switch on the right side, so I figure power should enter there first.  The red / purple lines from there represent 3-conductor wire leading to the second switch.  From there, I use 2-conductor wire, the black line represents the one for the recessed lighting (not pictured is the first light in the hallway), and the purple one represents the one for the island pendant lighting.
I also have undercabinet lighting which I figure should be controlled from the backsplash, so I've put that on its own circuit in green.  This circuit doesn't necessarily need 3-way switching so I've just left it simple.

Will this setup work, or is there another recommended method?
Thanks for reading!

Please explain why you have 2 cables between the two switches at the bottom?

You know I was just drifting off to sleep yesterday when I realized I only need one 3-conductor cable between them, as it can supply power to both sets of switches in parallel!  Thanks for the question @RobertChapin :)

The way you have it laid out is fine, but you do need two separate wires between the two switches. You need a three-wire for the pendants and a two-wire for powering your recessed cans. If you plan on adding another three-way for your recessed cans, add another three wires.

@RatTent Ah ok, thank you for the clarification!  Yes I do intend on having two separate sets of three-way switches for the pendants and recessed lights.
